# Assigning a value from one list to another using class instances

Tags: ruby

I'm quite stuck on how to figure this out. I would like to assign one list attribute to another when I do

```
class System
# can access from outside of class
attr_reader :id, :os, :basebox

    def initialize(id, os, basebox, vulns=[], networks=[])
    @id = id
    @os = os
    @basebox = basebox

    @data = {
     "vulns" => vulns,
     "networks" => networks  
    }
end
 end

class Basebox
attr_accessor :name, :os, :distro, :vagrantbase, :url
end


p base
p system
```

the cut output is

```
#<Basebox:0x007fbc4b12a7c8 @name="precise",  @vagrantbase="precise32">

#<System:0x007fbc4b12bb00 @id="system3", @os="linux", @basebox="test">
```

and if I do

```
p base.vagrantbase
p system.basebox
```

the output is

```
"CentOS6.2withpuppet"
"test"
```

which I would expect.

i want to assign @vagrantbase value to @basebox value but when i do

```
system.basebox = base.vagrantbase
```

I receive undefined method `basebox='

Comment: show the class also.. only output wouldn’t help..

Comment: @arup added the classes

Comment: Changing `attr_reader` to `attr_accessor` for `@basebox`, as @Arup suggests, is best, but this also works: `system.instance_variable_set(:@basebox, base.vagrantbase)`.
You should edit to show `system = System.new(...)` and `base = Basebox.new(...)`, including their respective arguments, and fix the indentation.

Comment: thanks for that cary, they are already instantiated beforehand in other methods with System.new i thought i set it to attr_accessor i actually realised my mistake once i uploaded the code and re-read through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *class* `System`, `attr_reader :id, :os, :basebox` wouldn't create the setter method `#basebox=` for you. You need to write as below :

```
attr_reader :id, :os # if you don't want to have #id= and #os=
attr_accessor :basebox # but you want both #basebox= and #basebox
```

Read this [`#attr_reader`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader) and [`attr_accessor`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor) methods.

Comment: i feel stupid now, i forgot to check the class, knew it would have been something stupid should have done the rubber ducky method and started from the beginning instead of presuming it was the list itself :P